# JPA - Using param values in return for select

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

Sample code below illustrates better what I want to achieve. I want to be able to inject values to my query so these values are in resultset already, instead of having to loop over Resultset to add the extra data.

ExampleModel

```
data class ExampleModel(
    var transactionDate: Date? = null,
    var totalTransactionAmount: Long? = null,
    var totalTransactions: Long? = null,
    var payerName: String? = null
)
```

Try 1:

```
@Query("select new example.model.ExampleModel(cast(te.dateCreated as date), sum(te.amount), count(te), :paramValue) from ExampleEntity te group by cast(te.dateCreated as date), te.transactionStatus")
fun findAggregatedExamples(@Param("paramValue") paramValue: String): List<ExampleModel>
```

Stack Trace at Server start up:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [example.model.ExampleModel]. Expected arguments are: java.util.Date, long, long, long [select new example.model.ExampleModel(cast(tr.dateCompleted as date),sum(te.amount), count(te), :payerName) from example.entity.ExampleEntity te group by cast(te.dateCreated as date), te.transactionStatus]

Try 2:

```
@Query("select new example.model.ExampleModel(cast(te.dateCreated as date), sum(te.amount), count(te), ':paramValue') from ExampleEntity te group by cast(te.dateCreated as date), te.transactionStatus")
    fun findAggregatedExamples(@Param("paramValue") paramValue: String): List<ExampleModel>
```

Stacktrace at Runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [payerName] did not exist
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.findParameterRegistration(BaseQueryImpl.java:487) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:638) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:32) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:139) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQueryParameterBinder.bind(StringQueryParameterBinder.java:61) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.bind(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:161) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:152) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:202) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:128) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:118) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:494) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 121 common frames omitted
```

Comment: why are you returning a String Literal that says ":paramValue"? Remove the quotes if you want to return the parameter (for whatever reason)

Comment: why do you want to call a select with an additional static value just to have it returned in the result set again? ... don't know for what such a roundtrip should be good for...

Comment: @BillyFrost - if i remove the quotes, jpql considers it a long value somehow !

Comment: @Roland if i do not do it this way, I have 2 other choices :
1. a very complicated join with some if else, and join to multiple tables just to retrieve the paramValue
2. Loop over the resultset and add the paramValue to my model. Above is just an example I made, but in reality this will be used to extract reports on demand, and amount of data could be massive over the long run

Comment: Which comes down to how "Spring Data JPA" is passing things to the JPA API (the problem with using API abstractions on top of other APIs). If it thinks its a "long" then post the full exception in that case and people can see where that comes from.

Comment: Do you have any control over this `ExampleModel`?

Comment: @BillyFrost - THANKS A LOT :) I think I spent too much time with the problem yesterday and eventually gave up to do some other things. Reading you post with a fresh mind today, I found and fixed the issue. I will add the trace to the initial question, so it saves others time as well. And I will post the answer below. In brief, I had to cast that value to a string, and that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting the value as string did the trick. Similar to the cast to date which I already had in the same query !

```
@Query("select new example.model.ExampleModel(cast(te.dateCreated as date), sum(te.amount), count(te), cast(:paramValue as string)) from ExampleEntity te group by cast(te.dateCreated as date), te.transactionStatus")
    fun findAggregatedExamples(@Param("paramValue") paramValue: String): List<ExampleModel>
```